# bash: Accessing function call stack in trap function

Tags: bash, function, error-handling, trap

Working on a bash function call stack trace...

Script traps errors and runs a `callStack()` function. But on trapping, It always shows a call stack for the `callStack()` function itself instead of the function where the trap occurred as in ...

```
/share/sbin/zimdialog: line 647: status: command not found
    Function call stack ( command.function() ) ...
      /share/sbin/zimdialog.main()
        /share/sbin/include.callStack()
```

Looking to get a stack trace that includes the `errantFunction()` like...

```
/share/sbin/zimdialog: line 647: status: command not found
    Function call stack ( command.function() ) ...
      /share/sbin/zimdialog.main()
        /share/sbin/zimdialog.errantFunction()
          /share/sbin/include.callStack()
```

The trap is coded as...

```
trap callStack HUP INT QUIT TERM ERR
```

The `callStack()` function is coded as...

```
function callStack () {
  { isNotNull "$1" && isHelp "$1"; } && {
    helpShow 'callStack
    Diagnostics regarding where the call to this function came from'
    return
  }
  local T="${T}  "
  local STACK=
  i=${#FUNCNAME[@]}
  ((--i))
  printf "${T}Function call stack ( command.function() ) ...\n" >&2
  T="${T}  "
  while (( $i >= 0 ))
  do
    STACK+="${T}${BASH_SOURCE[$i]}.${FUNCNAME[$i]}()\n"
    T="${T}  "
    ((--i))
  done
  printf "$STACK" >&2
}
```

---

**Supplemental: set -E, etc. not working**

In `/share/sbin/gshlib` ...

```
set -e
set -E
set -T
shopt -s extdebug

trap $(callStack) ERR

function initialize () {
    :
  logstatus                         #<<< ERROR FOR TESTING trap
}
export -f initialize
```

Misnaming `logStatus` to `logstatus` within `/share/sbin/gshlib.initialize()` to spring the `trap ERR`, the best I get is...

```
    Function call stack ...
    | /share/sbin/archive.main()
    |   /share/sbin/include.include()
    |     /share/sbin/gshlib.source()
    |       /share/sbin/include.callStack()
/share/sbin/gshlib: line 109: logstatus: command not found
```

What I'm looking to get is...

```
    Function call stack ...
    | /share/sbin/archive.main()
    |   /share/sbin/include.include()
    |     /share/sbin/gshlib.source()
    |       /share/sbin/gshlib.initialize()
    |         /share/sbin/include.callStack()
/share/sbin/gshlib: line 109: logstatus: command not found
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to `set -E` (or `set -o errtrace`) so that the `trap ERR` is inherited by called functions.

Once you do that, you'll probably find that you'll get a cascading error report, since each function in the call stack will be terminated (with a non-zero exit code) by the script error.

`ERR` is not triggered by invocation of a shell function in a context where failure is not considered fatal (like `if` or `while`). In such a context, the stack trace will probably not appear, although I'm not sure how version-specific that is.